# Application works fine on the simulator but crashes on the device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My app worked fine on my device but when I test on my device (iphone 4 iOs 4.3.3) some time it work , some time it crashes.This is the crash log when it crash. Can you please tell me where is the problem or how to find it

```
Date/Time:       2011-12-15 23:21:55.719 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.3.3 (8J2)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000b
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34499c98 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreFoundation                  0x308e3cd6 CFRetain + 62
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309940b8 __CFBasicHashStandardRetainValue + 8
3   CoreFoundation                  0x30995438 __CFBasicHashAddValue + 100
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308e3ff0 CFBasicHashAddValue + 276
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308e9d6c CFDictionaryCreate + 64
6   CoreFoundation                  0x308e977c -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 1196
7   CoreFoundation                  0x30910890 -[NSDictionary initWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 532
8   Myapp                           0x000488c4 -[FormViewController resultUpload:] (FormViewController.m:509)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x308edefc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
10  Myapp                           0x00026dbe -[ASIHTTPRequest reportFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2016)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x308edefc -[NSObject(NSObject) performSelector:withObject:] + 16
12  Foundation                      0x342427a2 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 262
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30959758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
17  CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
18  GraphicsServices                0x30269418 GSEventRunModal + 108
19  GraphicsServices                0x302694c4 GSEventRun + 56
20  UIKit                           0x30a10d62 -[UIApplication _run] + 398
21  UIKit                           0x30a0e800 UIApplicationMain + 664
22  Myapp                           0x000025a8 main (main.m:14)
23  Myapp                           0x00002550 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x355903ec __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356676d8 _pthread_wqthread + 592
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35590fbc kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x35261032 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 706
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3526203a _dispatch_queue_invoke + 86
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x352615ea _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 186
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566758a _pthread_wqthread + 258
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bbc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   WebCore                         0x35f5327e _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 382
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc00 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558d758 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x309582b8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 88
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3095a562 __CFRunLoopRun + 350
4   CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
5   CoreFoundation                  0x308eadc4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
6   Foundation                      0x341dd7f6 +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 206
7   Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
8   Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558fc60 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3095d8f2 __CFSocketManager + 582
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558dc2c semaphore_signal_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3558df92 semaphore_signal + 2
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x356645f4 pthread_mutex_unlock + 188
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3449ae2c objc_sync_exit + 44
4   Foundation                      0x341bfb7a -[NSThread _nq:] + 586
5   Foundation                      0x341bf7ec -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:modes:] + 724
6   Foundation                      0x341bf2e6 -[NSObject(NSThreadPerformAdditions) performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:] + 94
7   Myapp                           0x00026d0a -[ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:2008)
8   Myapp                           0x0002e464 -[ASIHTTPRequest handleStreamComplete] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:3503)
9   Myapp                           0x0002bfa2 -[ASIHTTPRequest handleNetworkEvent:] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:3187)
10  Myapp                           0x0001baa2 ReadStreamClientCallBack (ASIHTTPRequest.m:54)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x308ffa1a _signalEventSync + 70
12  CoreFoundation                  0x30900626 _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 198
13  CoreFoundation                  0x30957a72 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 6
14  CoreFoundation                  0x30959758 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 376
15  CoreFoundation                  0x3095a4e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 224
16  CoreFoundation                  0x308eaebc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
17  CoreFoundation                  0x3092d6d2 CFRunLoopRun + 42
18  Myapp                           0x00035cba +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] (ASIHTTPRequest.m:4789)
19  Foundation                      0x341d0382 -[NSThread main] + 38
20  Foundation                      0x342425c6 __NSThread__main__ + 966
21  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3566630a _pthread_start + 242
22  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35667bb4 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x1fdd8e10    r1: 0x312bd814      r2: 0x00000003      r3: 0x34a80c89
    r4: 0x00000003    r5: 0x3e7d62b4      r6: 0x00000020      r7: 0x2feed640
    r8: 0x00000008    r9: 0x2feed68c     r10: 0x00152d84     r11: 0x2feed6dc
    ip: 0x00000008    sp: 0x2feed628      lr: 0x30ecacdd      pc: 0x34a80c98
  cpsr: 0x000f0030

Binary Images:
   0xf0000 -   0x147fff +Myapp armv7  <5cac5a4eefa73eee9dd22e1ee04c20ca> /var/mobile/Applications/11660961-0E37-4121-A8A5-5EE99EFB342A/Myapp.app/Myapp
  0x192000 -   0x192fff +MobileSubstrate.dylib armv6  <4070bd34b2c273416bcec248fd8b873d> /Library/MobileSubstrate/MobileSubstrate.dylib
  0x1c7000 -   0x1c8fff +SubstrateLoader.dylib armv6  <ff6a576a67626b81229111c8c4169d09> /Library/Frameworks/CydiaSubstrate.framework/Libraries/SubstrateLoader.dylib
 0x1270000 -  0x1295fff +Activator.dylib armv6  <a930347f472e332ba6a2f6809f12e335> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/Activator.dylib
 0x12a6000 -  0x12aafff +IntelliStatusIconsView.dylib armv6  <915699e8cb5c1a129984cec679515c50> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/IntelliStatusIconsView.dylib
 0x12b4000 -  0x12b5fff +sandcastleclient.dylib armv6  <d138ce2db8b033aba6119acf3d561535> /Library/MobileSubstrate/DynamicLibraries/sandcastleclient.dylib
 0x12b8000 -  0x12bbfff  libsubstrate.dylib armv6  <5f24c4f6863b75d701ee663ed761c423> /usr/lib/libsubstrate.dylib
0x2feef000 - 0x2ff14fff  dyld armv7  <bb9bfc7d242331d29a79adf7ef7aaa18> /usr/lib/dyld
0x305ec000 - 0x30615fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <57fef84bdc17301d8bf53ba0fb967fe6> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x30616000 - 0x3064dfff  Security armv7  <6599f42a910b3b31a0e1d98c883d61cb> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3064e000 - 0x3064ffff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <39bf0f48bd8539169a77f8f61cdcd4c9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x306ac000 - 0x306acfff  Accelerate armv7  <7d5ad465049136afaa1f0d89aac600bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x307aa000 - 0x3083ffff  ImageIO armv7  <d520e3241d1130e8ac1375ee0f2c1095> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x3084c000 - 0x30858fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <ff78a9636e933f0dbd222f8d26209788> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x309b7000 - 0x309b9fff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <a2631ac302f4310dae8367939e16b7c2> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x309ba000 - 0x30ad4fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <bada0c2725bb31a483d5adf9aaf1f8df> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x30ad9000 - 0x30aeffff  EAP8021X armv7  <9fefc0ada30435fbb3b51818c74f6cb8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x30c7d000 - 0x30c84fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <55f29184efcc3046bb833dd72a4487e1> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x30c91000 - 0x30c91fff  vecLib armv7  <0c60cd0a60f43d2791d36cb357d30e3c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30cce000 - 0x30d0bfff  CoreText armv7  <fb6a72faec2330c4b2cd33c2e9c59588> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x30ec9000 - 0x30faefff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a8444f997111304c9571b3ff974b769c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x30fc9000 - 0x31356fff  UIKit armv7  <c271b78464d93cb7bf28c6e49df293ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31377000 - 0x31464fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <f4146ce07e3031ea8a81fa5516fd77d0> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x31465000 - 0x31466fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <e8858a499d663e6a9e3c188521273cc1> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31477000 - 0x31480fff  CoreVideo armv7  <ea847e6dba2d36b1826b255c73b39539> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x314d1000 - 0x314d3fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <d55f1553d14831a2a5435ae27ef75ef4> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x314d4000 - 0x31525fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <8a41cc6a6d9332308bc415d27577fd24> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3153f000 - 0x31546fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <0a082e1d475432959ba93aa3dbf7fb31> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3158b000 - 0x31590fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <f5ccc8234aea3ebd9a88bd37f0fa23ae> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x315cb000 - 0x315d6fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <ac706bee36593dc683fd5a96a389d72e> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x31747000 - 0x31747fff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <21415179ffa03f949fa8cc851c6c31c7> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x31748000 - 0x31749fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <ccc041df3de73eafb7a59e74cdb1702b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x3174a000 - 0x3176afff  PrintKit armv7  <e5a01ca9083a36afacc08611a398e2ad> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x31777000 - 0x317b9fff  CoreAudio armv7  <c972fd5f8e89333ca680b9a33587f896> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x31d8c000 - 0x31dc4fff  IOKit armv7  <80ae313ad69d3363935c88e51a11862d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x31e05000 - 0x31e41fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9d97699e44ee3651ba4ac37e5adec35b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x31e6c000 - 0x338bafff  TextInput armv7  <f242acc046073c1598195dd26fd8ad6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x33a07000 - 0x33a0cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <8c35c090bc373cb181fc26b961b8dba5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x33a0d000 - 0x33a16fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <03d98d5cf6383695aa7d8a88da52f410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33b24000 - 0x33b6afff  CoreTelephony armv7  <af7d1e770e5a3ffd8834a57fb5d40557> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x33b6b000 - 0x33b77fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <c68262667ac8397a949ce4e92dfec7db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x33c4c000 - 0x33c4efff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <683f321680763e519d61541170ba2133> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x33c4f000 - 0x33c54fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <e57c2b9054b831d9a37119baaa4947cb> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x33d40000 - 0x33d44fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a0772a32cd8b3b9194bb0c29807c1c5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33e7a000 - 0x33e7efff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <e1cbfe599c96369ca4bdb0dd99d3cd9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x33e80000 - 0x33f31fff  WebKit armv7  <eb9a0d69c64b3127b2bffd71641add3b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x33f32000 - 0x33f3ffff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <0a1e2bb78d5138419ecad8ba0fe42fdd> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34018000 - 0x3401efff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <14c89b7346433c1f8675f454531f6ca3> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x342f9000 - 0x342fafff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <41a7b5e5d9983449ab33affed0f635ad> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x34367000 - 0x3436afff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <43311c113a9d3182b7d007129819f029> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3436b000 - 0x34380fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <e92cfbb83f7b330db19181e797bb3f7b> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x34587000 - 0x3458afff  IOSurface armv7  <ad50e71624583d06b891344d832f9b08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3458b000 - 0x345d9fff  GMM armv7  <049361f664eb3f30b0d25cd56ffc1f0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x3468b000 - 0x346eafff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <0b36b2272aa33a8c9aa22d99c89d7189> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3479a000 - 0x348b9fff  Foundation armv7  <09ff368178c5321c9715b9c8d491d53f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x34986000 - 0x34a35fff  QuartzCore armv7  <ef9632c9781f3101916b65e9faae1579> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34a36000 - 0x34a7cfff  CoreLocation armv7  <c1924042951e3df98515c7bf36093c1c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x34a7e000 - 0x34b42fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <6b51e76fde9f381bb7b3bc5badbfee3a> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34d28000 - 0x34d5bfff  AppSupport armv7  <0217468bd9f839229a47910b7816b3d5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34d5c000 - 0x34d63fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <ab9777b39e8e3026ad64dc90323cad7e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34d66000 - 0x34e87fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <65f6c8701b563542820a26b0dfc4f6a4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x34ec8000 - 0x351b5fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <b855d60dac01310495453bddfd004f0d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x351e1000 - 0x35216fff  AddressBook armv7  <3f2071a77bc134cd82065eef90d4082f> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x35217000 - 0x352d6fff  CFNetwork armv7  <b09e0d53de9f3bc8bde494780f3cdd4f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x352d7000 - 0x352f0fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4825c3e392983aba947eca06555e4480> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x35411000 - 0x35565fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <6619c8c13f8d328e923e797fa8d0df23> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35606000 - 0x35607fff  CoreSurface armv7  <7b83cd757da73e6e826693c29296d3fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3560c000 - 0x356b5fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <5538d3f2c7d83b88b06168488fe6326b> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x356e0000 - 0x356e5fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <c7cfe523e2d73521abc01587313ef730> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x357d3000 - 0x357f0fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <48016be86e3f3cd9aeee1c6590e1ac6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3583d000 - 0x35841fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <d2f7fd2a352b3cd59c564be34b53cf80> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x35842000 - 0x3584ffff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9a0511ad5ebc3db898f1f49ed1a73d34> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x35880000 - 0x358bffff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <33dcf9a403ae3fd5971d6030ada2fcab> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x358c0000 - 0x358c0fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <42d8aa2a31843a6e8bfff745644a7ba5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x3595f000 - 0x359cefff  ProofReader armv7  <6d843c6aecdd37ae84baa40af8ad7e65> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x359cf000 - 0x35a24fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <0221caba81a235c5a896a835e2aac047> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35a32000 - 0x35b5efff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <113de5f9858c32b8b158bfdc68042a97> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x35b61000 - 0x35b64fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <fc834fd33a18341ea7506587ad895703> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x35b65000 - 0x35b7cfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <a06ec84e53bf32098b63c0caebdb45b6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35bcb000 - 0x35c15fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <b2cac408951c3f3c9ba3cf563e54ce81> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35c16000 - 0x35c18fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <94b6d6c5d9883175af26764567528127> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x35c1a000 - 0x35c9bfff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <a7077267b6743ed3bbdd86d4380c75d9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35c9c000 - 0x35cd4fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <ccea634795153164a681f0f311f4461d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35d9c000 - 0x35d9dfff  TextInput_fr armv7  <df896624a716399f877087d35f6c6d86> /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_fr.bundle/TextInput_fr
0x36100000 - 0x36204fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <61a94142e2d23dafa2964190dd46e9e3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36262000 - 0x36281fff  Bom armv7  <b178e3efb4d733c694bd5a55e57a314f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36534000 - 0x36b3ffff  WebCore armv7  <07941e59d0a33f94802c16c76238fddf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x36b40000 - 0x36b46fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <f9277ee9b85b3722975ad319a323aca0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x36c14000 - 0x36c43fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <1d73b8a159363f96bb9c039655c5eae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x36c4d000 - 0x36c5bfff  OpenGLES armv7  <5a76beaeaa013f0cbf16e5cb154598ab> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x36c6e000 - 0x36c73fff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9d7198e91de9386a9e5ea43608a66a57> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x36d76000 - 0x36d76fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <f47c01d627853b328e088b3fdd08e87d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
```

this is my code

```
-(IBAction) validate:(id)sender
{
     // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  //  [mdata addObject:userId];

//    [mdata addObject:pseudoField.text];
//    [mdata addObject:birthdateField.text];
//    [mdata addObject:sex];
//    [mdata addObject:countryField.text];
//    [mdata addObject:cityField.text]; 


    if([pseudoField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [birthdateField.text isEqualToString:@""] ||
       [countryField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [cityField.text isEqualToString:@""])

    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Veuillez remplir tout les champs" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [alert show];


    }
    else
    {

    if (mail == nil || mail==NULL)
    {
        mail=@"NULL";
    }

    if (token == nil || token==NULL)
    {
        token=@"NULL";
    }

    if (tokenExp == nil || tokenExp==NULL)
    {
        tokenExp=@"NULL";
    }


    if (altitude == nil || altitude==NULL)
    {
        altitude=@"NULL";
    }

    if (longitude == nil || longitude==NULL)
    {
        longitude=@"NULL";
    }

        picActivity.hidden=NO;
        [picActivity startAnimating];



        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320,480)); 
        [userImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,480)];
        UIImage *m = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        NSData* mageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(m, 0.5); 
        NSString *hash;
        hash=[self md5:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userId]];

        NSString * myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.info/upimage.php?n=%@",hash];  
        NSLog(@"url string %@ ",myURLString);
        NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];

        NSString * myPictureUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite.info/uploads/%@.jpg",hash];
        [self setPictureLink:myPictureUrl];

//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.info/upimage.php?n=HGJHJHjh"];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        // Upload a file on disk
        [request setData:mageData withFileName:@"photo.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"file"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        request.didFinishSelector = @selector(resultUpload:);
        request.didFailSelector = @selector(imageError:);

        [request startAsynchronous];






  //  NSLog(@"Validated Data %@ : ",dict);


}
}



-(void)imageError :(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    [picActivity stopAnimating];
    picActivity.hidden=YES;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur De Connexion" message:@"l'application n'arrive pas à se connecter au serveur " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alert show];
    }

-(void)resultUpload :(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    picActivity.hidden=YES;
    [picActivity stopAnimating];
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"seccess upload image , result : %@",responseString);
    if([responseString isEqualToString:@"error"])
    {
       NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userId, @"userID", pseudoField.text, @"pseudo", birthdateField.text,@"birthdate",sex,@"sex",countryField.text,@"country",cityField.text,@"city",mail,@"mail",token,@"token",tokenExp,@"token", tokenExp,@"tokenEpr", altitude,@"altitude",longitude,@"longitude",pictureLink,@"pic", nil];

          NSLog(@"Validated Data %@ : ",dict);
       // [pictureLink release];

        AnalyseViewController *analyseViewController =[[AnalyseViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnalyseViewController" bundle:nil];
        analyseViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:analyseViewController animated:YES];


    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur De Connexion" message:@"l'application n'arrive pas à se connecter au serveur " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
        [alert show];

    }

}

- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
    const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
    unsigned char digest[16];
    CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

    NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return  output;

}
```

this line 509 is NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc ....

Comment: Please supply the crash log and the code from around  FormViewController.m line: 509

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at line 8 in the stack trace, the `FormViewController` `resultUpload:` method.

The best guess is that one of the objects file `FormViewController.m` line 509 is pointing to is over-released. This type of error does not always occur depending on memory usage/re-usage.

Check at each of these is valid: `userId, pseudoField.text, birthdateField.text,sex,countryField.text,cityField.text,mail,token,tokenExp, tokenExp, altitude, longitude, pictureLink`.

Set NSZombies in the scheme to help find this:
[image]

Many error do not occur every time and in every configuration. In this case it appears that the device configuration is uncovering an error in your code that by luck does not appear in the simulator. Also, the simulator has a different runtime than the device which may cause an error to appear in one and not the other.

Also, is there a crash log in addition to the stack trace?

Comment: there are nothong in line 8 :( no there are no more addition log, i will ipdate my post

Comment: No there is no missing bracket , it was deleted when i copy the code , it's NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:userId, @"userID", pseudoField.text, @"pseudo", birthdateField.text,@"birthdate",sex,@"sex",countryField.text,@"country",cityField.text,@"city",mail,@"mail",token,@"token",tokenExp,@"token", tokenExp,@"tokenEpr", altitude,@"altitude",longitude,@"longitude",pictureLink,@"pic", nil];

Comment: Fixed your code ? sorry but i don't understand :( i don't speak good english

Comment: i added the crash code after i enabled zombie objects but i thnik it's the same

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an error in your conditional statements.

```
if([responseString isEqualToString:@"error"])
{
   NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc initWithObjectsAndKeys:userId, @"userID", pseudoField.text, @"pseudo", birthdateField.text,@"birthdate",sex,@"sex",countryField.text,@"country",cityField.text,@"city",mail,@"mail",token,@"token",tokenExp,@"token", tokenExp,@"tokenEpr", altitude,@"altitude",longitude,@"longitude",pictureLink,@"pic", nil];

      NSLog(@"Validated Data %@ : ",dict);
   // [pictureLink release];

    AnalyseViewController *analyseViewController =[[AnalyseViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnalyseViewController" bundle:nil];
    analyseViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:analyseViewController animated:YES];


}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Erreur De Connexion" message:@"l'application n'arrive pas à se connecter au serveur " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

This will create the dictionary if your response string is @"error".  Try `if(![responseString isEqualToString:@"error"])`.

Comment: No no when it's ok the result is "error" :D it's for security

Comment: Ahh, security through obfuscation, huh? ;)

Comment: @Mehdi Obfuscation is not security. In this case it does make creating correct code maintaining it more difficult.

Comment: yeeees exactly :) @CocoaFu yes but it's nor really a problem , i think it's better than if i use , success , your image has been uploaded !

Comment: Why is something that is incorrect better? WIll it be better much later when someone else to you read it? Later @"error" will probably be meant to mean that there was an error, in fact that has already confused @Stoph and made it harder for him to help you. It is always better to write clear concise code.

Comment: @CocoaFu yes it's trues but i don't think someone else will read the code. I have to stop this, this is one of my bad habits